How to make kindle open PDF version 1.6?
I am an owner of Kindle Paperwhite gen 2021 15 which I bought a couple of months ago
I have a book in PDf which was rendered just fine on my Pocketbook 790, but Kindle refused to open it.
After some experiments I found out that PDF of version 1.4 an older did open on the eBook. So I suppose that is the culprit.
Unfortunately, I cannot convert my book to an older format with ps utility - everything is fine except for the cyrillic letter "A"(both capital and lowercase) - just a whitespace instead of every occurrence
Does anybody know a way to downgrade the PDF file OR make Kindle read the newer version?

Kindle Paperwhite can handle many file types. It might be easier to use a tool such as free Calibre, https://calibre-ebook.com, to convert to EPUB, MOBI, or other native format. Calibre also stores and indexes ebooks.

That's a great question! Converting a PDF to a Kindle-compatible format can be really handy, especially if you've got some interesting content you want to enjoy on your Kindle device.
To convert a PDF to a format that Kindle can open, you'll typically need to use a tool or software that can convert PDF files into Kindle-friendly formats like .mobi or .azw. One of the simplest ways to do this is by using online converters or dedicated software programs.
Here's a step-by-step guide to converting your PDF to a Kindle-friendly format:
Choose a Conversion Tool: There are many online conversion tools available for free that can convert PDF files to Kindle-compatible formats. Some popular options include Calibre, Zamzar, and Online-Convert.
Upload Your PDF: Once you've chosen a conversion tool, simply upload your PDF file to the platform. Make sure to select the desired output format compatible with Kindle, such as .mobi or .azw.
Convert the File: After uploading the PDF, initiate the conversion process. Depending on the size of the file and the speed of your internet connection, this may take a few moments.
Download the Converted File: Once the conversion is complete, download the converted file to your computer. This file should now be compatible with your Kindle device.
Transfer to Your Kindle: Finally, transfer the converted file to your Kindle device using either a USB cable or by sending it to your Kindle email address. Your Kindle should now be able to open the PDF in its converted format!
If you're looking for an even easier solution, I recently came across a fantastic digital book creation platform called AIGPT Book Creator. It offers a hassle-free way to create digital books and documents, including PDFs optimized for Kindle devices. They even have a special bundle offer right now that you might find helpful. You can check it out here.
Hope this helps, and happy journey on your Kindle!
